# apache server configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I am using Apache server to develop web applications in php . I have one Basic doubt .

Now to execute the php scripts from the browser should I add just this line to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

or should I add both the lines

```
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

Can someone explain the difference . If only one is required then which is faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're running is PHP scripts within the Apache server, then you only need the `php5_module` line.  On the other hand, if you're running CGI scripts (either PHP or another language) then you need the `cgi_module` line as well.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to load the cgi_module if you are only developing in PHP.

Just:

```
LoadModule php5_module "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/php5apache2_2.dll"
```

is sufficient